# Comprimir Imagen tomada con camara en javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

tengo el siguiente codigo que lo que hace es tomar una fotografia de una aplicacion creada con cordova javascript:

```
function cameraApp() {

        console.log("Tomar foto")
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 100,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
        });
        function onSuccess(imageData) {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            imagenenbytes = imageData.toString();
        }
        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Fallo: ' + message);
        }

    };
```

lo que quiero hacer es reducir el tamaño de la fotografia recien tomada de manera que tenga un tamaño menor a 1 mb.

en este caso aqui tengo una funcion en la cual pregunto el tamaño de la imagen obtenida pero como debo proceder para poder reducir el tamaño de la misma?

```
function comprimirImagen() 
    {
        if (imagenenbytes.length < 100000)
        {
            const porcentajedereduccion = 1000000 / imagenenbytes.length;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Reduce el valor de quality. Por ejemplo, cambia 100 a 90. Además, parece necesario indicar el ancho final y el alto final mediante las propiedades targetWidth y 
targetHeight. Por ejemplo:quality: 80, 
targetWidth: 150,
targetHeight: 100,

Comment: donde agrego eso?

Comment: En navigator.camera.getPicture(on success, on fail, { AQUI INCLUYES TUS NUEVAS PROPIEDADES }

Comment: en este caso si se me redujo el tamaño de la imagen pero no quiero reducirla mas de lo necesario

Comment: Entonces, hay 2 opciones. Primera opción, probar un valor menor que 100 para la propiedad quality hasta obtener un resultado decente. Segunda opción es usar una librería de JavaScript que se encarga de manipular imágenes. Por ejemplo, CompressJS

Comment: no hay una funcion a la cual pueda pasarle la cadena que se llama imageenbytes, para que esta la convierta en imagen y despues decirle que tome el width y el height de esa imagen y que la haga mas pequeña de acuerdo al porcentajedereduccion?

Comment: Hay unas librerias para js como cropper que te permiten manipular la imagen, entre otras escalarla. Lo que hacen esas librerias es meter la imagen en un canvas y hacen uso de todos los metodos de la api canvas de js. Croppie es una de las mas completas

Comment: Es muy difícil comprimir la imagen pensando el espacio que ocupará en disco, hay muchos factores a considerar como dimensiones, calidad, compresión, etc. Creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es definir un tamaño máximo (alto y ancho) y redimensionar. Tal vez te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297273/54039).